# How to populate list of applications with Sublime Editor

Tags: 16.04, default-programs, sublime-text

When a unknown file type is to be opened, a list of applications is presented and an application is chosen. What are the steps to add Sublime editor to the list in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I installed my sublime using it's deb file and after that I can see it in the list of programs to use, how did you install yours?

Comment: Look at the documentation : https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-application-user.html.en